# Synchronize SQlite with MySql

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to get synchronized my **`sqlite`** on android with my **`mysql database`.**
I want to make an input to `mysql` - and my android application should check every n second if there is a new entry in `mysql`, if yes then it shall `replace/update` the `sqlite database` which has the same structure as **mysql**.

Befor I start to try something, I would like to know which methods and ways there are I can chose for solving that problem. Maybe you have some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking from a `Service` will drain your battery and will consume resources as you will be checking each and everytime from your device that if an update in the MySql Database has happened or not. Don't you think that it will be better if the device is notified only (and automatically) whenever the Update in the MySql database is  perfomed .

[**Ever heard of GCM?**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Whenever you perform an update in MySql,just send notification of the same to the Android device and call an API to get the data fromthe servers

Comment: yes that would be better, but how can I do that...? because my mysql does not have anything to do with the android application - how can the application get a signal from mysql, that something has changed in mysql?

Comment: You need to implement server functionality

Comment: hey I am following the tutorial from your link - but is the usage of GCM free?

Comment: seems to be for free... thank you I think your idea is a good alternative - because the action is only done if it is neccessary.. thank you

Comment: i followed the tutorial, but the registration does not work
the error appears when I make a db entry
"multicast_id":.........."success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: You will need to call the registration method from the android application... and retrieve the registration id from gcm server...save it in your very own mysql database or wherever you want...it is the particular identity of your device...

Answer (score 0):

you should use background service and in that you should start a thread that never ends. and in that thread you can continuously hit request to mysql database if there is update available to your database than that update should be inserted into your sqlite database. and also you can keep track of newly inserted or deleted entry through primary key which is auto increamented.

Comment: hmm yes, that was also my thought... I am thinking of, as you said, to my a background service where it compares the mysql database with sqlite database every n second... ok thank you